# how to plot dot on the ridges of a surface?

Tags: matlab, plot, min

I cannot find a way to plot some dots on lower and upper ridge of my surface.
I wrote this code for surface:

```
%initialize parameters
x   = linspace(-2,2,100);
y   = linspace(-2,2,80);
fxy = abs(log(x'.*y));


% it looks like this 
figure(1), clf
surf(x,y,fxy')
shading interp
axis square, rotate3d on
xlabel('X'), ylabel('y'), zlabel('f(x,y)')
```

And for finding lower ridge I wrote something like the following:

```
% find min

minval = min(min(fxy));
[xi,yi] = find( minval == fxy);


idx = sub2ind(size(fxy),xi,yi);

% plot the minimum as a red ball
hold on
plot3(x(xi),y(yi),fxy(idx)','ro', 'MarkerFaceColor','r','MarkerSize',12 )
```

Then for lower bound (lower ridge) I set a threshold 0.1 and then:

```
% finding lower ridge : points below a threshold of .01

[xi,yi] = find( fxy < minval+.01);

% to get the values,  convert from matrix indices to linear indices
idx = sub2ind(size(fxy),xi,yi);

% plot the close-to minimum points
plot3(x(xi),y(yi),fxy(idx)','ro','markerfacecolor','r','markersize',12)
```

[image]

Now for maximum I did this:

```
% finding maximum
maxval = max(max(fxy));
[xi,yi] = find( maxval == fxy);
% plot the maximum as a red ball
plot3(x(xi),y(yi),fxy(xi,yi)','ro', 'MarkerFaceColor','r','MarkerSize',12 )
```

now how can I find upper ridge? I set threshold 5 for upper, and the result was like this:

```
% finding upper ridge : points below a threshold of 5

[xi,yi] = find( maxval- fxy <5);

% to get the values,  convert from matrix indices to linear indices
idx = sub2ind(size(fxy),xi,yi);

% plot the close-to minimum points
plot3(x(xi),y(yi),fxy(idx)','ro','markerfacecolor','r','markersize',12)
```

[image]

which would be is the the best threshold to obtain only upper ridge? is there any other way to plot dots only on upper edge?

Comment: What do you want to obtain as "upper edge"? What you need to consider is that using a rough, horizontal threshold for `f(x,y)` will result in all points above a horizontal surface (at about `z=3.2` in the image) being tagged. If you want true edges, that's a lot more involved than applying a simple 1D threshold. You'd need to somehow identify those edges using derivatives I presume.

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do, but mathematically, since `abs(log(0)) = inf` there is no such thing as "upper ridge". So it is weird to highlight a numerical artifact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the top ridges, in a general case I would follow Adriaan comment and look at the derivative (you can use the fucntion [`gradient`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gradient.html) for that).

However in your case there is another approach, made possible by the fact that:

- On any `X` slice of your surface `fxy`, the ridge `y` coordinate will coincide with the max value of this `X` slice.
- And, on any `Y` slice of your surface `fxy`, the ridge `x` coordinate will coincide with the max value of this `Y` slice.

Armed with this observation, the [`max`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html) function is all you need:

```
% Find maximum Z value and index for
[zxmax,idxzx] = max(fxy) ;          % All X slices (columns)
[zymax,idxzy] = max(fxy,[],2) ;     % All Y slices (rows)

xr = x(idxzx) ; % get the actual X coordinates from the column indices
yr = y(idxzy) ; % get the actual Y coordinates from the row indices

% Display
hold on
plot3(xr,y,zxmax,'r','LineWidth',4)
plot3(x,yr,zxmax,'b','LineWidth',4)

% Or if you want them dotted
% plot3(xr,y,zxmax,'or')
% plot3(x,yr,zymax,'ob')
```

This plotted on top of your initial surface display will render:

[image: Ridges highlighted]

Comment: ,Wonderful! many thanks for your intuitive answer, you know, I don't have any idea about how to use deivitive to find whole ridge. I know derivative can give me maximum (top point) , but how it can give all the points along the ridges? Should I use second dirivitie or something?

Comment: The derivative will change sign (go from positive to negative, or negative to positive) everytime the signal change in Z direction (respectively, from going up to down or down to up). Since your ridges are exactly that (the signal change in Z direction), you would try to look for the points where the derivative is = 0 (indicate a change of direction). Since the domain is discrete, you may not find a point where the derivative is exactly `0`, in which case you'd select the point the closest to `0` (among two points with different sign).